# ViewPager Flickers on touch inside empty area

Tags: android, android-viewpager, flicker

- I have a scenario in view ViewPager is used to display multiple fragments depicting number of columns
- Now in tablet when there are only two pages / column inside the view pager , there remains empty area in the view pager after the two pages as view pager is occupying full screen of the tablet.
- When the user touches this empty area the remaining pages start flickering scrolling back and forth in the screen.
- How to restrict user to touch in this empty area ? I also need to allow user swiping the pages to scroll , how to manage both the scenario.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this same scenario. My solution was to consume the touch event when there are less pages displaying than required to fill the viewpager

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); // not sure if this is required
            PagerAdapter adapter = viewPager.getAdapter();
            // consume the move event if we have only one page full - removes flickering artifact
            // getNumberOfPagesOnScreen() is a mehtod we have to get the number of pages we are going to display. ymmv
            if (adapter.getCount() <= adapter.getNumberOfPagesOnScreen() && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tnx working for me. Once a while still jumps form left to right, but still ok

Comment: Thanks, after so many years, I had to use ViewPager and this solution came to rescue with a small modification for my needs.

Comment: how to get adapter.getNumberOfPagesOnScreen() method?

Comment: 1. requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) seems to be not required.
2. "getNumberOfPagesOnScreen()" describes the number of items inside your viewpager in a screen width. You can determine it in yourself.